# How to add a responsive registration/login form into the middle of a website that is connected to mysql server?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have tried to link to another html/php file which includes the form but now I want to put the form right on the website. I'm just kinda confused by the way it use to connect to phpmyadmin and how to set it up. Also both of the methods ended up showing just simple and ugly text and buttons rather than the one I wanted. Is there a sample code that I can use for the form? It'll be great if there's an explanation of connecting to phpmyadmin and connect the html file to a group of php file. 
[image: screenshot reference]Thank you.

Comment: You need to learn about PDO.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp Should help you with the form handling there should be some examples of mysqli function here for you to start.

Comment: If you already have a form, why do you need a sample form anyway? just use the one you have and then use some `css` to prettify it. then you need to use `php`, `mysqli` or `PDO` to connect to your `db` and do the registration/login process...